# Solving System of Inequalities Relatively

Tags: equation-solving

I have been trying to figure out how to solve a system of inequalities relatively. I don't care about values, I just want all possible ordering. An example system might be:$${b > r,\; p > r,\; c - 1 = p,\; c < x,\; h > x,\; h < e, }$$
$${r < k,\; q > k,\; l - 1 = q,\; l < h,\; k > p}$$

I want to get all possible ways they could be arranged in order, satisfying the inequalities. If I am not explaining this well, please let me know, I'm not sure how to describe what I'm looking in a more mathematical way.

Is there a straightforward way to do it? I tried using `Reduce` over the domain of `Integers`, but it choked. `FindInstance` was able to find a single instance, but not more than that.

Edit:
I tried:

```
FindInstance[{ b > r, p > r, c - 1 == p, c < x, h > x, h < e, 
               r < k, q > k, l - 1 == q, l < h, k > p}, 
             { b, r, p, c, x, h, e, k, q, l}]
```

> ```
> {{b -> 0, r -> -1, p -> 0, c -> 1, x -> 2, h -> 3, e -> 4, k -> 1/2, q -> 1, l -> 2}}
> ```

This is basically what I'm looking for, but when I tried increasing `n`, I let it run for `5+` minutes and never got a solution.

I also tried:

```
Reduce[{ b > r, p > r, c - 1 == p, c < x, h > x, h < e, 
         r < k, q > k, l - 1 == q, l < h, k > p}, 
       {b, r, p, c, x, h, e, k, q, l}]
```

> ```
>  b ∈ Reals && r < b && p > r && c == 1 + p && x > 1 + p && h > x && 
>  e > h && p < k < -1 + h && k < q < -1 + h && l == 1 + q
> ```

when I tried `Reduce` over the domain `Integers`, the output was several hundred lines long.

**Edit :** Sorting by the second element, the revised version is:

```
 DeleteDuplicates[
   Map[ First, Map[ SortBy[ #, Last] &, 
                    FindInstance[{ b > r, p > r, c - 1 == p, c < x, h > x, h < e, r < k, 
                                   q > k, l - 1 == q, l < h, k > p}, 
                                   { b, r, p, c, x, h, e, k, q, l}, 10]
                  ], {2}]]
```

Comment: Please share your  `Reduce[]` and `FindInstance[]` codes with us

Comment: @belisarius just added

Comment: Re:your Edit. Your `Map[First, ...]` is getting the name of the variables only ... and they (the names) are always the same (of course). I don't get your point

Comment: @belisarius You're correct, I meant to sort by the second element. I posted a corrected version. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try for example:

```
FindInstance[{b > r, p > r, c - 1 == p, c < x, h > x, h < e, r < k, 
             q > k, l - 1 == q, l < h, k > p}, {b, r, p, c, x, h, e, k, q, l}, 15]
```

which gives you 15 different solutions

Comment: Very odd, I just realized when I was trying it, I specified the domain `Integers`, which never gave a solution. But without integers, it does it instantly..

Comment: I actually am not sure that works. I don't think those solutions are unique. See my edit above.